# Number of connected components of a $C^{*}$ algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Inspired  by the concept in the following post
[What are these compact sets called?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130797/what-are-these-compact-sets-called)
We introduce the following concept:

Let $A$ be  a unital $C^{*}$ algebra. We consider the unitary equivalent relation on the set of all projections in $A$. We denote by $n(A)$, the number of equivalents classes of projections in $A$. The number of connected components of $A$ is denoted by $ncc(A)$ and is defined by $ncc(A)=log_{2} n(A)$. For  a  non unital $C^{*}$ algebra $A$, we define $ncc(A)=ncc(M(A))$ where $M(A)$ is  the multiplier algebra of $A$. This  is  a  natural definition because for  a locally compact Hausdorff   space $X$ we have $ncc(C_{0}(X))=$ The number of  connected components of $X$.

The concept in the above post is  a motivation to ask:

**Question 1:**  Assume that We have  an extension $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$   of $C^{*}$ algebras with $ncc(A)< \infty$  and $ncc(C)< \infty$. Does this  implies that $ncc(B)$ is  finite, too? How can $ncc(B)$ be  controlled  by $ncc(A)$  and  $ncc(C)$?

**Question 2:** How can $ncc(A\otimes_{min} B)$ be  controlled in term of $ncc(A)$  and  $ncc(B)$?  When $A$ is  commutative, is  it true  to  say that $ncc(A\otimes B) \leq ncc(A).ncc(B)$?

**Note:**  The  commutative  case gives us enough  motivation  for  such noncommutative   questions.

Comment: As a sign of good faith, why don't you tell us what you've been able to work out when A is a noncommutative finite-dimensional Cstar algebra?

Comment: @YemonChoi  For the matrix algebra  n(A) is  n+1.So when A,C are finite dimensional algebra, the first question is obvious, the second is not  a so hard(for large value n, m)

Comment: Thanks. So according to your definition, $ncc(M_n({\bf C}))= \log_2(n+1)$? This seems slightly odd, and it's not clear to me why this definition is better than looking at equivalence classes of projections in stabilized versions of the algebra (i.e. $K_0)$.

Comment: Also, why does an answer for the matrix algebra case tell you what is going on for the finite-dimensional case? It seems perfectly possible that if $A\subset M_n({\bf C})$ then two projections in $A$ could be unitarily equivalent in $M_n({\bf C})$ without being unitarily equivalent in $A$...

Comment: @YemonChoi  Thank s for your comments.yes it is possible. for example $A=M_{2}(\mathbb{C})\oplus  M_{2}(\mathbb{C})\subset M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$. Let  $e\in M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be the projection on $x$-axis. Then $e\oplus I_{2}$  and $I_{2} \oplus e$ are similar in the whole algebra but not similar in $A$. after all, I think the main question in the post is obvious for finite dim algebras since any such algebra is a direct sum of matrix algebras.